# Mathematical "urban legends"

Tags: ho.history-overview

When I was a young and impressionable graduate student at Princeton, we scared each other with the story of a Final Public Oral, where Jack Milnor was dragged in against his will to sit on a committee, and noted that the class of topological spaces discussed by the speaker consisted of finite spaces. I had assumed this was an "urban legend", but then at a cocktail party, I mentioned this to a faculty member, who turned crimson and said that this was one of his students, who never talked to him, and then had to write another thesis (in numerical analysis, which was not very highly regarded at Princeton at the time). But now, I have talked to a couple of topologists who should have been there at the time of the event, and they told me that this was an urban legend at their time as well, so maybe the faculty member was pulling my leg.

So, the questions are: (a) any direct evidence for or against this particular disaster?
(b) what stories kept **you** awake at night as a graduate student, and is there any evidence for or against their truth?

**EDIT** (this is unrelated, but I don't want to answer my own question too many times): At Princeton, there was supposedly an FPO in Physics, on some sort of statistical mechanics, and the constant $k$ appeared many times. The student was asked:

Examiner: What is $k?$

Student: Boltzmann's constant.

Examiner: Yes, but what is the value?

Student: Gee, I don't know...

Examiner: OK, order of magnitude?

Student: Umm, don't know, I just know $k\dots$

The student was failed, since he was obviously not a physicist.

Comment: Since every finite CW complex is weakly homotopically equivalent to a finite topological space, that does not sound *so* bad... :)

Comment: I heard a version of this too, from sources I thought were reputable
(but I forget who, probably more than one.)

Comment: Perhaps not an urban legend per se, but when I was learning algebra, my professor, in an attempt to impress upon us the necessity of checking that certain maps are well-defined, told us the story of a classmate of his who got several years into his Ph.D. thesis before realizing that the maps he was investigating weren't well defined. Horrified, we asked him if this was true. "No" he said, "but that's one lie you'll never forget!"

Comment: I had heard an urban legend about Milnor sitting in on a dissertation defense, but in this story the speaker airily discussed a certain natural transformation, that Milnor expressed doubted it was natural, and that Milnor was right. According to the story, the thesis was completely invalidated because the student hadn't checked naturality, and had to start all over (or something like that). 

Comment: Maybe I hung around the wrong crowd, but I've never heard Igor's story. True or not, it'd be a shame if that story somehow got lost before my generation.

Comment: I also had heard an urban legend about Milnor sitting in on a 
dissertation defense (long ago when I was a graduate student a Brandeis). In the version I had heard the class of new topological space that were studied was observed by Milnor to consist only of the empty set.

Comment: Well, and of course there is the old chestnut of the (supposedly Harvard) student who wrote a thesis about the class of functions satisfying a Lipschitz condition of order \(1 + \epsilon \)  :-)

  But getting back to the original question, why not just ask Milnor?

Comment: @Dick: is that the one Qiaochu recorded below? 

Comment: Willie Wong asked:"@Dick: is that the one Qiaochu recorded below?", and it no doubt is. Perhaps I will add more detail. I first heard it when I was  grad student myself at Harvard (so if you know when I got my degree you will realize how old a legend this is !). Moreover the story as I heard it was that the thesis advisor was Garett Birkhoff. 

Comment: Mathematical urban legends have been collected by Steven Krantz in the book, Mathematical Apochrypha (and I think there's a second volume). A few refer to the thesis defense. 

Comment: For some decades after the alleged event, a story persistently circulated that a certain professor at a certain institution had fallen out of a window while lecturing.  I would tell you some specific reasons why this might have somewhat plausible, but then too many people might guess who it was.

Comment: I should proofread before hitting the "add comment" button.

Comment: Though this question and its answers are very entertaining, I think it is a little unfair to close other questions as "offtopic" which are even closer to mathematical research as this one ...

Comment: @ Mariano: I gather that what is meant is that the space is just a finite set of points with the discrete or indiscrete topology.

Comment: Another good source of such legends is *Absolute Zero Gravity*, by Betsy Devine and Joel E. Cohen.

Comment: I have to agree with Martin.  This is a very entertaining thread but it seems quite outside the mandate of MO. 

Comment: Martin, you should definitely raise your point on meta. Objectively, you're completely right. But I'm enjoying this as long as it manages to remain open.

Comment: So I'm a hypocrite :) Blame Ryan and Martin for convincing me. 

Comment: The details in the question appear garbled to me. However, I was present when Katz asked Milnor about the story that he had once asked a question at a thesis defense which had sunk the thesis. Milnor looked embarrassed, and said that it had happened. He added that he hadn't been trying to trip up the student --- he had asked the question simply out of curiosity.

Comment: See "heckled by your talk host" under http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/hecklers-and-twecklers-at-technical-talks/

Comment: In case anyone comes upon this question later, the decision to close it after 70 (!) answers was made here : http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1054/legends/

Answer (score 193):

This happened just last year, but it certainly deserves to be included in the annals of mathematical legends:

A graduate student (let's call him Saeed) is in the airport standing in a security line. He is coming back from a conference, where he presented some exciting results of his Ph.D. thesis in Algebraic Geometry.  One of the people whom he met at his presentation (let's call him Vikram) is also in the line, and they start talking excitedly about the results, and in particular the clever solution to problem X via **blowing up eight points on a plane**.

They don't notice other travelers slowly backing away from them.

Less than a minute later, the TSA officers descend on the two mathematicians, and take them away.  They are thoroughly and intimately searched, and separated for interrogation. For an hour, the interrogation gets nowhere: the mathematicians simply don't know what the interrogators are talking about.  What bombs?  What plot?  What terrorism?

The student finally realizes the problem, pulls out a pre-print of his paper, and proceeds to explain to the interrogators exactly what "blowing up points on a plane" means in Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: Anna--Pedro Teixeira and I had a couple of papers where we introduced operations of the following sort: one starts with a function f on
[0,1] and replaces it by the function x-->f((x+7)/25), x in [0,1].
We originally called such operations blowing-ups but thought it more
prudent to call them magnifications in the published papers.

Comment: Was it Vikram Mehta ?  

Comment: Efim Zelmanov told a similar story:  he was stopped by the KGB on his
way to a conference and questioned at length about his books on "free groups" and "radicals".

Comment: Thank god the diligent TSA caught their nefarious *scheme*.

Comment: I hope I'm not being a killjoy, but I've heard versions of this story so many times over the years that I'd be quite interested to find out if this one is alleged to be true and by whom. Do you know?

Comment: Anna's story is about my officemate in grad school (who is a friend of Anna's brother, one of our classmates). He was flying from London to the US right after the waterbombing incident. He studies DP1's. They ended up strip searching him. Eventually he got through.

Comment: I remember being joking about the potential that something like this could happen with some mathematicians probably in 2004 or so.  We were at an airport, but were careful not to discuss even joking about it too near security.

Comment: Georgia Benkart once (probably in 1979 or 1980) related a vaguely similar story about some famous mathematician and the Killing form. In my imagination, the event she described took place in the McCarthy era, but honestly I don’t remember the details. Maybe it was Zassenhaus. Then again, maybe it was someone else, though I’m pretty sure it was Zassenhaus she told about in the artichoke story.

Comment: Well, you know what they say about algebraic geometers: they blow up families, and then the come back afterwards to make sure that they're flat.

Comment: +1: "annals of mathematical legends"

Answer (score 147):

Since this has become a free-for-all, allow me to share an anecdote that I wouldn't quite believe if I hadn't seen it myself.

I attended graduate school in Connecticut, where seminars proceeded with New England gentility, very few questions coming from the audience even at the end.  But my advisor Fred Linton would take me down to New York each week to attend Eilenberg's category theory seminars at Columbia.  These affairs would go on for hours with many interruptions, particularly from Sammy who would object to anything said in less than what he regarded as the optimal way.  Now Fred had a tendency to doze off during talks.  One particular week a well-known category theorist (but I'll omit his name) was presenting some of his new results, and Sammy was giving him a very hard time.  He kept saying "draw the right diagram, draw the right diagram."  Sammy didn't know what diagram he wanted and he rejected half a dozen attempts by the speaker, and then at least an equal number from the audience.  Finally, when it all seemed a total impasse, Sammy, after a weighty pause said "Someone, wake up Fred."  So someone tapped Fred on the shoulder, he blinked his eyes and Sammy said, in more measured tones than before, "Fred, draw the right diagram."  Fred looked up at the board, walked up, drew the right diagram, returned to his chair, and promptly went back to sleep.  And so the talk continued.

Thank you all for your indulgence - I've always wanted to see that story preserved for posterity and now I have.

Comment: David, do you remember what the topic was?

Answer (score 135):

Here's another great one: a certain well known mathematican, we'll call him Professor P.T. (these are *not* his initials...), upon his arrival at Harvard University, was scheduled to teach Math 1a (the first semester of freshman calculus.) He asked his fellow faculty members what he was supposed to teach in this course, and they told him: limits, continuity, differentiability, and a little bit of indefinite integration.

The next day he came back and asked, "What am I supposed to cover in the second lecture?"

Comment: A little more context from (the version I heard) of this one: the mathematician’s previous experience had been in the USSR — I think in Moscow.  (This hopefully adds something useful without getting too specific…)

Comment: This is really not specific, because in the USSR one was taught these concepts in school.

Comment: well, and in large parts of the rest of europe, too.

Answer (score 106):

Although David Hilbert was one of the first to deal seriously with infinite-dimensional complete inner product spaces, the practice of calling them after him was begun by others, supposedly without his knowledge.  The story goes that one day a visitor came to Göttingen and gave a seminar about some theorem on "Hilbert spaces".  At the end of the lecture, Hilbert raised his hand and asked, "What is a Hilbert space?"

Comment: This appears in Krantz's _Mathematical Apocrypha Redux_ (the second edition of the book mentioned by Gerry Myerson in the comments).  According to this version the speaker was von Neumann, the lecture occurred in 1929, and Hilbert is quoted as saying "Dr. von Neumann, ich möchte gern wissen, was ist dann eigentlich ein Hilbertscher Raum?"  (The translation given: "Dr. von Neumann, I would very much like to know, what after all is a Hilbert space?")

Comment: (By the way, I thought this book would be mostly funny stories, but it is full of sobering tidbits about how mathematicians were affected by anti-Semitism, the Nazis, the Great Depression, and McCarthyism. Interesting stuff.)

Comment: There is another version of this story in which Weyl is the one being asked by Hilbert.

Comment: In Emilio Segre's version of this (very popular) story, as recounted  in Segre's <i>Autobiography</i>, the speaker was Enrico Fermi and the year was the late 1930's.  "Fermi attended [Robert] Oppenheimer's seminars; coming out of one of them once, he said: 'Emilio, I must be getting senile.  I went to a learned theoretical seminar and could not understand anything except the last words, which were "And this is Fermi's theory of beta decay."'"

Comment: To this day, in the building in Göttingen in which Hilbert worked, there is an actual "Hilbert space" (the German mathematical word for space is "Raum" which also happens to be the German word for "room").

Comment: I heard also from somewhere that Hilbert was very disappointed at the answer and said "is that all?", or words to that effect, since he thought the definition so trivial.

Comment: This is similar to Lars' comment above. On the bottom floor of the math building at Lund University (Sweden) you'll find a students' cafe named "Hilbertrummet" (which means both "the Hilbert room" and "the Hilbert space").

Comment: Congrats on the first golden badge! :-)

Answer (score 102):

A legend that I heard from my father, who heard it from ... ... ...: Levi-Civita was teaching a course in a room on (what Americans call) the second floor of a building.  One day, as a prank, his students "borrowed" a donkey from one of the fruit vendors on the street in front of the building.  Somehow, they brought this donkey up the stairs into the lecture hall and had it standing there as Levi-Civita entered to begin his lecture.  Levi-Civita set his notes down on the lectern, looked up at the class, commented "I see we have one more today," and proceeded with his lecture.

Answer (score 94):

Here is a story I heard many years ago, and have no confirmation of:

Apparently, there was Asst Professor X at a provincial department Y, and he was up for tenure. Professor X's advisor was a famous Japanese mathematician Z at an Ivy League school. Naturally, he was asked for a letter, which he duly sent. The letter said:

X has a very nice body of work, he proved the following interesting theorems, extended such and such results, used such and such techniques... and so on for two pages.
The last sentence was: all in all, X is a very good second-rate mathematician.

The committee was mortified, but figured that the rest of the letter was so good, they should call Z, since maybe since English was not his native language... So, call they did, and the phone conversation went about the same as the letter: did this, improved that, ..., all in all a very good second-rate mathematician.

The committee then said: look, we don't understand why you say he is second-rate!!!

to which Z replied: well, I really can't understand why that would be a problem -- after all, you are a **third** rate department.

Comment: Who cares if it's true or false? That's what makes urban legends so fun! It's shocking, and yet we feel sure that somewhere some similar incident must have happened...

Comment: Andre Weil's law of university hiring (according to Wikipedia, undocumented): "First rate people hire other first rate people. Second rate people hire third rate people." This always left me wondering, who hires the second rate people? Maybe Igor's story answers my question. 

Comment: "And third rate people hire fifth rate people."

Comment: @Gerry The second rate people always hire.

Comment: Maybe the fourth rate mathematicians hire the second rate ones, and that's how they keep their jobs in the hiring department?

Comment: Ah, I understand. Nth-rate people are hired by mth-rate people, where m is the closest integer to n/phi.

Comment: From the Chronicle of Higher Education: http://chronicle.com/article/You-Were-Too-Good-for-Us/46833

Comment: @Philip, that's a really perceptive (unfortunately...) article, and certainly something I had seen happen...

Answer (score 82):

The following story is a bit strange to be true, but we all believed it as students, and I think I still do believe that a somewhat weaker version of events must have indeed occurred.
[Michael Maschler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Maschler) (most famous in Israel as author of the standard math textbooks for middle-schools and high-schools) was in the middle of teaching an undergraduate course- I think it was Linear Algebra- when one afternoon he walks into the lecture hall and announces the discovery of a new class of incredible Riemannian symmetric spaces with incredible properties, missed by Elie Cartan. The undergrads have no idea what he is on about; but the faculty all get very excited, and start sitting in on his Linear Algebra course. Ignoring the syllabus, Prof. Maschler begins to give lecture upon lecture about the new incredible symmetric spaces which he discovered. The excitement builds. Will he win a prize? Will he win the Fields Medal?...
And then, 3 lectures in, a student (some say it was Avinoam Mann, about whom many stories are told) gets up and asks, "Excuse me, sir. How can you distinguish your space from a sphere?"
Maschler turns to answer the "stupid question", but he freezes in mid-motion... Gradually, his face turns white. The lecture hall is so silent you can hear a pin drop. Finally, after what seems like an eternity, Prof. Maschler unfreezes. "By golly, a sphere it is," he murmurs in an undertone. And he picked the Linear Algebra textbook up from his desk, and resumed teaching where he had left off. The subject was never broached again.
And so, some Hebrew University students of my generation call spheres "Maschler spaces".

Answer (score 81):

I've heard that in the earliest days of communist Hungary, Pal Turan was stopped on the street by a patrol. These patrols were charged with collecting a quota of people to be shipped off to Siberia (Stalin was still in charge, and arbitrary punishment is a big part of inducing the Stockholm Syndrome). While being searched and interrogated for his "crimes", the policeman was surprised and impressed (and perhaps a bit intimidated himself) to find a reprint of a paper of Turan's published pre-war in a Soviet journal. Turan was allowed to go free. That day, he wrote a letter to Erdos beginning, "I have discovered a most wonderful new application of number theory..."

Comment: Turan was in forced labor camps during much of the second war. This sounds like an incident I read about that took place in one of those camps. I wonder if we haven't had a conflation of two dictatorships. 

Comment: Perhaps we should consider "urban legends" as parasites (or symbiotes) on the mathematical ecosystem. They certainly mutate and (as Gerry indicates) perhaps even have sex.

Comment: I've tracked down the incident I read about. It's in Szego's preface to Hungarian Problem Book I, which was volume 11 in the New Mathematical Library. It's too long to write out here. Szego doesn't give a source, doesn't claim all the details are accurate, and doesn't name the mathematician. In short, X was in a forced labor camp circa 1940, the supervisor recognized his name from Hungarian problem-solving competitions, and gave him more lenient treatment. The story is also quoted in Rosemary Schmalz, Out Of The Mouths Of Mathematicians, MAA 1993

Comment: Now I have found an unimpeachable source for Szego's story; Turan himself wrote it up in "A note of welcome," J Graph Theory 1 (1977) 7-9. 

Comment: Here is the text from "A note of welcome". 
In September 1940 I was called in for the first time to labor-camp service. We were taken to Transylvania to work at railway building. Our main work was carrying railway ties. It was not very difficult work but a spectator could of course easily recognize that most of us-I was no exception-did it rather awkwardly. One of my more expert comrades said this at one occasion quite explicitly, even mentioning my name. An officer was standing nearby, watching our work. When hearing my name, 
he asked the comrade whether or not I was a mathematician. (Contd)

Comment: It turned out that the officer-Joseph Winkler by name- was an engineer. In his youth he had placed at a mathematical competition; in civilian life he was a proofreader at the printing shop where the periodical of the Third Class of the Academy (Mathematical and Natural Sciences) was printed and had seen some of my manuscripts. He could do no more than assign me to a wood-yard where big logs, necessary to railroad building, were stored, classified according to their diameter; my task was merely to show incoming groups the place where they could find those logs with the prescribed width.

Comment: While there is no mention of the purported letter to Erdos, he does say that in the following few days, while assigned to the wood-yard, he proved Turán's theorem.

Answer (score 73):

A wholly different set of "named urban legends" (in order of time):

Allegedly, Jacobi came to show Gauss his cool results on elliptic functions. Gauss' response was to open a drawer, point at a sheaf of papers, and say: that's great you are doing this! I have actually discovered these results a while ago, but did not think they were good enough to publish... To which Jacobi responded: Funny, you have published a lot worse results.

When the logician Carnap was immigrating to the US, he had the usual consular interview, where one of the questions was (and still is, I think): "Would you favor the overthrow of the US government by violence, or force of arms?". He thought for a while, and responded: "I would have to say force of arms..."

Finally, on the graduate experience front, it was rumored at Princeton that Bill Thurston's qualifying exams at Berkeley were held as his wife was in labor with his first child -- the department refused to change the date for such a minor reason! I have just asked him about this, and it's true...

**EDIT** A certain (now well-known) mathematician was a postdoc at IHES in the late 1980s. Call him R. R comes to lunch, and finds himself across the table from Misha Gromov. Gromov, very charmingly, asks him what he was working on. R tells him, Gromov has some comments, they have a good conversation, lunch is over. The next day R finds himself across from Gromov again. Misha's first question is: so, what are you working on *now?*

Comment: I'd never heard the Carnap story.  It's reminiscent of Godel's US citizenship test.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_G%C3%B6del#Relocation_to_Princeton.2C_Einstein_and_US_citizenship

Comment: Gauss was some 20 years older than Jacobi and was, well, Gauss. It would have take *great* nerve...

Comment: http://www.egglescliffe.org.uk/physics/physicists/feynman.html


Comment: The Thurston story is recounted in his interview in More Mathematical People. 

Comment: Around the Jacobi/Gauß anecdote: the correspondence between Jacobi and Legendre is fascinating and worth reading. It's quite moving to see this old mathematician welcoming with enthusiasm the work of two younger ones (Jacobi and Abel) following the study of his favorite mathematical field. It's almost melodramatic, with episodes of anger against Gauß (Legendre has had his share of paternity disputes with him, for example regarding the quadratic reciprocity law or the law of least squares) or mourning after Abel died...

Comment: ... And as usual with mathematical texts of this time, the elegance of the language is baffling. Particularly so if one remembers that Jacobi doesn't write in his mother tongue.

Comment: Reiman István's book *A geometria és határterületei* tells a similar story about Gauss.  In that one, the other party is Bolyai János, the discovery concerned is hyperbolic geometry, correspondence is through mail only (not in person), and Gauss gives a different reason why he didn't yet publish about the topic.


Answer (score 73):

Another urban legend, which I've heard told about various mathematicians, and which Misha Polyak self-effacingly tells about himself (and therefore might even be true), is the following:

As a young postdoc, Misha was giving a talk at a prestigious US university about his new diagrammatic formula for a certain finite type invariant, which had 158 terms. A famous (but unnamed) mathematician was sitting, sleeping, in the front row. "Oh dear, he doesn't like my talk," thought Misha.
But then, just as Misha's talk was coming to a close, the famous professor wakes with a start. Like a man possessed, the famous professor leaps up out of his chair, and cries, "By golly! That looks exactly like the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch Theorem!!!"
Misha didn't know what to say. Perhaps, in his sleep, this great professor had simplified Misha's 158 term diagrammatic formula for a topological invariant, and had discovered a deep mathematical connection with algebraic geometry? It was, after all, not impossible. Misha paced in front of the board silently, not knowing quite how to respond. Should he feign understanding, or admit his own ignorance? Finally, because the tension had become too great to bear, Misha asked in an undertone, "How so, sir?"
"Well," explained the famous professor grandly. "There's a left hand side to your formula on the left."
"Yes," agreed Misha meekly.
"And a right hand side to your formula on the right."
"Indeed," agreed Misha.
"And you claim that they are equal!" concluded the great professor. "Just like the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch Theorem!"

Comment: This sounds like a whole generation of French-educated algebraists has never seen an equation in their whole life :D

Comment: I guess nowadays one has the analogous "But that is a special case of the (coarse) Baum-Connes conjecture for (quantum) group(oid)s" ...

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, Victor Ginzburg once said something like: "that's a Langlands correspondence, because it's a correspondence between two sets" in a seminar.

Answer (score 71):

This story was told to me by my advisor.

A Ph.D. student in logic was having an extremely difficult time finishing his thesis and was starting to succumb to hopelessness. Every evening he would trudge home, open a beer, and sit down in front of the television. This was the 1960's. Evidently there was a running show called Whiz Kids that showcased the achievments of child prodigies; I'm imagining something of a Johnny Carson style setting involving banter with an unctuous host before a studio audience. One week, the young [Harvey Friedman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Friedman) was on the show. The host asked Harvey what he had been up to recently, to which the latter responded that he had proved that "every end extension of a model of standard arithmetic has an elementary submodel such that..." and on to the technical details, much to the amusement of the studio audience. The student watching home at that moment realized: that closes precisely the gap I need to finish my thesis!

Comment: The version I heard of this story the show was the Guinness Book of World's Records show hosted by Flip Wilson.  While I don't know if the story is true, I have seen a photo of Harvey with Flip Wilson.  Also this show aired in 1970 which fits the time frame.

Comment: Hi Dave, as you know, Anand is a good story teller. It struck me has having too many specific details to be entirely made up. Nevertheless, "urban legend" seems to me to be the best categorization. 

Comment: This Whiz Kids: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiz_Kids_(TV_series) ? That was in the eighties…

Comment: Maybe not such an urban legend: according to Ali Enayat, it was The Flip Wilson Show in 1971, and the PhD student was Joram Hirschfeld. See page 10 here: http://cage.ugent.be/programFriedman/slides/Enayat_Ghent_Friedman%20%28ver.%202%29.pdf Update: No, it was a show called The Record Makers, hosted by Flip Wilson. Air date: April 2, 1971 on NBC. See http://fultonhistory.com/newspaper%208/Schenectady%20NY%20Gazette/Schenectady%20NY%20Gazette%201971%20Grayscale/Schenectady%20NY%20Gazette%201971%20Grayscale%20-%203510.pdf

Answer (score 69):

This is a story that I heard from one of the postdocs from my university, which in turn heard it from one of the professor at the university (I didn't bother to verify with him as the source seems relatively reliable).

The said professor was a postdoc in some university in the USA a few decades ago, and he was teaching a basic course on group theory. One of the homework assignments had a question of the form:
"Let $G_1$ be the group $\ldots$, and $G_2$ be the group $\ldots$ Prove that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic."

One of the papers submitted had an answer "We will show that $G_1$ is isomorphic..." and some nonsense, followed by "Now we'll show that $G_2$ is isomorphic..." and more nonsense.

Comment: All too believable, unfortunately.

Comment: I gave a homework problem, "Let $G_1$ be the group $\dots$, let $G_2$ be the group $\dots$. Are $G_1$ and $G_2$ isomorphic?" and was astonished to get the response, "$G_1$ is, but $G_2$ isn't." Are Asaf's story and mine isomorphic?

Comment: @Gerry: Asaf's is, but yours isn't.

Comment: You've been a lovely audience. Nate and I will be here all week. 

Comment: This is the same syntax as the joke "Oh Harry, if only we were married!" "We are, Sally... Oh, did you mean to each other?"

Comment: Don't forget to tip your server!

Comment: José Figueroa-O'Farrill tells a very similar story in a comment at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist/1748#1748

Comment: I was once told about a philosophy essay that started "In this essay I will argue that the mind is identical to the brain, but not the other way around".

Answer (score 65):

Here is another scary example (known to be true, by way of two of the participants): a (then) young postdoc approached R. Langlands and A. Borel (this was in the late seventies), in the IAS tea room, and the following conversation ensued:

Postdoc: Do you guys know anything about automorphic forms?

B&L: Maybe

Postdoc: Well, can I ask a stupid question?

B&L: Well, you have already asked *one.*

Comment: I've heard this same story with "automorphic forms" replaced by "algebraic groups" and "tea room" replaced by "grounds". The effects of the telephone game have caught one (or both) of us! (Judging from my source of the story, I'm guessing it's me...)

Comment: This story also appears in André Weil's Souvenirs d'apprentissage. I was certain he attributed the rebuttal to himself, but I may be wrong. If I remember correctly it went "Puis-je vous poser une question stupide?" - "Vous venez de le faire".

Comment: The version in Milne's apocrypha (http://www.jmilne.org/math/apocrypha.html) is slightly different:
$$ $$
A newly arrived member of the Institute for Advanced Study went up to two senior looking people and asked if either of them knew anything about representation theory. Being Borel and Langlands, they answered "yes". "Well," said the member, "do you mind if I ask you a stupid question?" "You already have" responded Langlands.




Comment: The beauty of this story is that when you tell it to people, they all laugh but if you go one step further, they disagree on *which* of the two questions was stupid...

Comment: This story clearly comes in many variants.  In my favorite, the Langlands retort to "do you mind if I ask you a stupid question" is

"That's two already."

Comment: In my first year I asked my professor in linear algebra, Schoenhage,
whether he knew how to compute with large numbers (I was trying to write a program for testing the primality of Fibonacci numbers).

Comment: I once gave a seminar, and in response to a question from an unknown audience member, launched into an exposition of Baas-Sullivan theory.  The organiser gently interrupted me: "I don't think you've met Nils Baas ..."

Comment: In view of Neil Strickland's story (and a couple of narrowly-averted disasters of my own), young mathematicians are urged to be cautious when fielding questions of strangers... I might add that sometimes, your audience background ends up being very different from what you expected; it's seldom good news.

Answer (score 64):

At the Hebrew University, during a complex analysis course, the professor states and proves the famous "Liouville's theorem", that every entire bounded function is constant. One confused student, trying to get some general clarification, asks "maybe you can give an example?". The professor without hesitation answers "yes, Of course. 7" and continues... we all sat still trying not to laugh so that the confused student wan't be embarrassed, but he was still quite embarrassed though...

Answer (score 61):

This one happened - I was there (as an observer, not a principal). Only the names have been changed.

X was Professor A's first doctoral student, and their relations weren't good. Rumor had it that the first time A saw most of X's thesis was when X handed in the final draft.

By the rules, there had to be a non-mathematician on the thesis defense committee - let's call him Professor H. Professor H made a valiant effort to read the thesis, understandably didn't get very far, but decided he was going to ask a question at the defense, to justify his being there in the first place. So he says to X, I notice you didn't provide a proof of your Lemma 2.3.1 - how does it go? X says, well, 2.3.1 isn't my work, it's a well-known result of van der Corput.

This satisfies H, but A says, OK, it's a result of van der Corput - but, how do you prove it? Well, X was prepared to answer questions on his own work, but hadn't brushed up on all the previous work that his thesis rested on. He hummed and hawed, started to give a proof, got stuck - at which point A gave him a hint. Using the hint, X got a little farther, but got stuck again - so A gave him another hint. This went on for an excruciating fifteen minutes (which, I'm sure, felt like 15 years to X), until finally Professor N broke the tension by saying, say, just whose thesis defense is this anyway, X's or van der Corput's?

Answer (score 61):

When I was at the University of Oklahoma in the early '80s, we were all required to write a brief description of our research for the (rather conservative, this being Oklahoma) Board of Regents of the University.  An colleague in algebra, perhaps hoping for more state support, wrote that he was studying "annihilating radical left ideals."

Comment: I think we've come some distance from "what stories kept you awake at night as a graduate student," but this reminds me that the Harvard course catalog, circa 1970, contained a math course described as "theory of blowing-up, with special attention to local problems." 

Comment: as an introduction to an integration technique, i remember my calculus professor saying something like "Much like the Republican party, our plan is to isolate the radical so we can get rid of it."

Comment: A friend is studying Lie Algebras, and told me once that the opposition used his grant to criticizing the goverment for wasting money on the study of "Theory of Lies"

Answer (score 60):

I have heard the following story from a few sources (among them, I think, an MO thread, possibly Terence Tao's blog, and Richard Lipton's blog), so it might even be true.

The story goes that once upon a time a student wrote his thesis on Hölder-continuous maps with $\alpha > 1$, since he had only seen the case $\alpha \le 1$ addressed in his books.  The student proved many wonderful theorems about these maps and was very excited for his defense.

At his thesis defense, one of the examiners (is that the right word?) asked him to provide a nontrivial example of such a map.  The student was flustered.  As it turns out, all such maps are constant - no wonder the theorems were so nice.

Comment: That is a scary story: it paints a picture of mathematical education of extreme sadness! 

Comment: This was the first urban legend I thought of when I read the question.  I heard it during grad school, probably in 2004 or 2005, but I don't recall from whom.  I had the impression it was already a well-established legend.

Comment: I heard this story from Andras Vasy a few days ago.

Comment: I have also heard this example, it seems to be more common than the one in the OP's question.

Comment: I heard this story in the fall of 09 at a conference in Florida. But I can't remember who told it to me.

Comment: My (over 15 year old) recollection places this story in a previous millenium.  Gerhard "Not As Old As Dirt" Paseman, 2011.01.24

Comment: As I commented above, I heard the story (with Lipschitz instead of Holder) back in the 1950s, so it is a really old legend.

Comment: I've heard this many times, and the question of which spaces these functions are defined on has always been omitted; presumably it is a manifold. I actually spend quite a lot of time working with non-trivial functions defined on compact totally disconnected spaces which are Hoelder with an exponent higher than $1$.

Comment: By the way, in my version, the student was specifically studying the Banach space of such functions, and was eventually told that he was studying $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I hear a similar story a few years ago, where a student proved exciting theorems about holomorphic functions with compact support.

Answer (score 58):

A certain Greek professor, let's call him AF, happened to have attended medical school in the US before becoming a professional mathematician.

He attended a talk by another mathematician, who claimed to have proved in N dimensions a result which AF had struggled to prove for N=2. Disconcerted, he spent the entirety of the talk constructing a counterexample to the speaker's result.

At the end of the talk, when questions were invited, AF walked up to the board and wrote down his counterexample. He turned around as he heard a loud thump from behind him. The speaker had fainted.

Undeterred, AF used his medical training to revive the speaker before returning to his seat.

Answer (score 56):

Some time in the early 90s Goro Shimura was giving a lecture course on algebraic number theory at the ENS in Paris. According to someone who was in the audience, one of the lectures started thus.

Let $a$ be a rational number. [Pause; the lecturer writes $a$ on the blackboard.] Is this clear? [Pause.] Do you follow me? [Long pause.]

Ok then. [Pause.] Let $\beta$ be an irrational number. [Pause; the lecturer writes $\beta$ on the blackboard.] Is this clear? [Pause.] Does everyone understand? [Long pause.]

Ok then. So consider a global field of prime characteristic and an automorphic representation of an algebraic group over its adelic ring. Now take the absolute Galois group and the  category of perverse l-adic sheaves on ...

[The third phrase here is a random and probably inaccurate reconstruction, but I'm pretty sure the numbers were called $a$ and $\beta$.]

upd: I've emailed the person I heard this from and they provided the following version. It seems that I got everything wrong; apologies. Anyhow, the course took place at Jussieu, not ENS and began thus.

Professor Shimura:

Consider alpha algebraic number, writes alpha on the blackboard, pause
(on the same line) now theta transcendental number, writes theta, pause
(below the first line) f holomorphic function, writes f, pause
(on the same second line below theta) g non-holomorphic function,
writes g, pause

long silence which I interpreted as "think deeply about the meaning of
this square"

Professor Shimura takes a deep breathe and in one sentence restarts:

Let f be a Siegel modular form of weight k and level N ....

Comment: This pattern of behavior occurs with surprising frequency. I have always found it very interesting.

Comment: Sorry; (as you admit) automorphic representations and (especially) perverse  $\ell$-adic sheaves does not sound like the Shimura I know, love and fear. I have two colleagues who are former students of the master: perhaps I should ask them to suggest something more plausible? 

Comment: Pete -- yes, by all means! The only thing I'm sure about, apart from the $a$ and the $\beta$, is that the level of difficulty increased rather steeply after the first two phrases. I've tried to convey this impression while adding some details for dramatic purposes (or else this wouldn't be much of an urban legend, would it?). On the other hand I can ask the person I heard it from (and who was sitting in that lecture) for a more accurate account.

Comment: @algori: well, I didn't see your response until just now, so it's probably too late.  But I forgot to mention that -- like any good urban legend -- in spirit your story rings true.  As an undergraduate I remember marveling at how much time certain professors spent explaining the most trivial things, only to race through the hard stuff in a big ball of frenetic activity.  And now, as an instructor, I see myself doing the same thing at times!  I guess we think, "Well, I really don't want to lose anyone on the first day" and at some point we think that we've lost the people we're going to lose...

Comment: This happens very often in text books ...

Answer (score 55):

I have no idea whether this one is true - I heard it at Harvard, around 1970. The story goes that a PhD student was so sure no one would ever read his dissertation that he stuck in the middle of it an offer to send fifty dollars to the first five people who asked. Every few years he'd get a letter from someone who stumbled across the offer, and he'd pay out.

Comment: Something like this has certainly happened at least once, though the legend probably predates it: http://www.snopes.com/college/homework/foundcar.asp

Comment: Very nice!${}{}$

Comment: Coincidentally, I recently found forty dollars in the middle of a book on moduli spaces I had checked out from the library.

Comment: Visiting a friend's place in graduate school, I saw many brand new GTMs on his shelf. Or at least their condition was as good as new. Suspecting some of these books would remain unread for a while, I stuck a small note in one GTM which said "Today is [date here]. Let me know when you find this note. [Signature]" I heard from him a couple of years after he finishes grad school.  

Comment: Another story: suspecting students were not reading solutions I was writing to homework in an abstract algebra course, in the middle of one solution I inserted the sentence "I will give a free chocolate bar to the first person who reads this." Nobody claimed the chocolate bar. Or maybe I offered an orange?

Comment: Someone once claimed to me that they had actually done this.  

Comment: A friend of mine signed me up for a free subscription to a "men's magazine" of the PG-13 variety. I took the 12 issues and stuffed them in obscure parts of the journal stacks in the library at the think tank where I was working. Before long one was found by a friend of mine purely by accident. I'm sure many are still there, though.

Comment: In the Caltech library there is a very big tome on combinatorics which I once idly opened at random.  In it, I found a letter from an undergrad in the 1970s, who wrote this letter to posteriority saying that although he enjoyed working on his project, he was disheartened by the fact that nobody would probably ever care about it.  

Answer (score 50):

George Mackey is reported to have been overheard saying "I'll *write* his thesis for him, but I'll be damned if I'm going to *explain* it to him."

Answer (score 46):

I am not sure where or when this happened, but I still think there may be some truth to the story.

Once someone from the engineering (or physics?) department of some university came to see Joseph Bernstein and asked if he knew a formula for a conformal mapping of the interior of a regular $n$-gon to the upper half-plane. Bernstein knew the formula, but decided to first ask what the person needed it for. The reply was: "Well, you see, what I really need is a formula for the unit disk, but that's probably too complicated, so I decided to find out the formula for the $n$-gon first and then take the limit."

Comment: Ouch.  Most of (the few) engineers I've met are much smarter than this.

Comment: Pete -- I should have been more explicit: I've heard this story several years ago during a late night conversation in Bonn and I can not really vouch for the details. It may have been biology or chemistry or something else. The moral however is, if I may say so, that one should be careful when speaking to someone who is about to apply mathematics. That is, if this person says they need to be able to solve a particular (difficult or hopeless) problem, it may be worthwhile to ask again.

Comment: @Pete: Engineers are smart, but you can't expect them to know all the math out there. In polynomial system solving, I've heard stories of engineers adding extra variables to lower the degrees of their equations. Anyone who is familiar with the complexity of Grobner bases will realize that this is **not** the way to go. But I'm sure it seemed to make sense at the time.

Comment: @algori: Spending a lot of time in Bonn, I always heard this only as a joke, not an urban legend. 

Answer (score 45):

Not an urban legend: I was there.

Abhyankar was speaking at Mumford's seminar, so Zariski, though long-retired, came to hear his former student speak.  Abhyankar began his talk by stating that he would only be working in characteristic 0.

Zariski interrupted to ask "Are there any additional difficulties in characteristic p?"

Abhyankar smiled and said "Only psychological difficulties."

Zariski turned to the audience and stated, most forcefully, "I have NEVER had psychological difficulties."

Comment: Another from the "I was there" file, Joel Hamkins may remember this from grad school: one Prof. (not J.) H. was lecturing on (related to Shelah's classification) something like omitting types, one of which was named p.  H. said "but we can't do this, else it loses its p-ness and can't fork anymore".  The class, not a mixed group, all laughed at this, and Prof. H. looked surprised. Some of us (Joel too, I think) later thought H. had worked that phrase in; it would be in character for H.  (Joel, feel free to tell your view of it.)  Gerhard "Don't Quote Me On This" Paseman, 2011.04.13

Comment: In a variation of the old "integral scheme of finite type over a field" story, I have actually seen Peter May answer the question "What's a ring?" with "Oh, a ring is just a Z-algebra."

Answer (score 43):

Here's something that keeps me up at night:

During the Russian revolution, there is a story of a mathematician (I've heard Igor Tamm may be the one) who was mistaken by rebels to be a communist spy. He was promptly captured by a local gang and interrogated. When he said that he is a mathematician, the gang leader asked him to back up his claim by deriving the formula for the Taylor Remainder Theorem. He was warned that if he failed, he would be shot on the spot. After some sweating the mathematician finally derived the result. The gang leader was satisfied with the proof and let him go.

Comment: So that's why when I was a first year graduate student at Harvard, the question "state and prove Taylor's theorem" appeared on the written qualifying exam! I think the professor who put this on the exam (we all thought it was Andy Gleason) was skeptical about whether the graduate students knew freshman calculus properly. As it happens, I knew how to do this only because I had been teaching freshman calculus that semester. Otherwise, I would have had to do some sweating, too.

Comment: I think a variant of the story asked for a derivation of the quadratic formula. Perhaps there should be a followup question of what one is expected to derive in their sleep...

Comment: According to Gamow, it was Tamm (references: http://books.google.com/books?id=G1ksgWOl2HEC&lpg=PA36&ots=KS_v44nd17&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q&f=false and http://www.springerlink.com/content/w0934gm403641227/ )

Comment: For some reason I feel slightly wistful for a world (or a time) where gang leaders even knew there was such a thing as the Taylor Remainder Theorem ...

Comment: @Yemon: what makes you so sure that gang leaders today don’t know it?

Comment: Russian math education is solid! even Gang leader know Taylor remainders...

Answer (score 43):

Here is another story from Krantz's *Mathematical Apocrypha Redux* which I thought was quite funny.

> One of the most common and popular Norbert Wiener (1894-1964) stories is of a student coming to Wiener after class and saying, "I really don't understand this problem that you discussed in class.  Can you explain to me how to do it?"  Wiener thought a moment, and wrote the answer (and only that) on the board.  "Yes," said the student, "but I would really like to master the technique.  Can you tell me the details?"  Wiener bowed his head in thought, and again he wrote the answer on the board.  In some torment, the student said, "But Professor Wiener, can't you show me how the problem is done?"  To which Wiener is reputed to have replied, "But I've already shown you how to do the problem in two ways!"
>
> Dick Swenson, who was at MIT in those days, tells this variant of the story: Wiener showed the kid the answer twice, as just indicated.  Then the student said, "Oh, you mean...," and *he* wrote the answer (and only the answer) on the board.  Wiener then said, "Ah, very nice.  I hadn't thought of that approach."

Comment: I've heard a version of this story with von Neumann as protagonist.  A student desperately trying to evaluate a definite integral at wit's end shows up at von Neumann's office for any suggestion of an approach.  Von Neumann thinks for a few moments and tells him the value of the integral.  The student, amazed and dismayed at the absence of any details, respectfully requests that von Neumann "explain it a different way."  Von Neumann thinks some more and cheerfully announces that both ways yield the announced value.

(I thought this story apocryphal even before hearing the Wiener version.)

Answer (score 40):

Oral maths exam for engineers, 1960s, Budapest. To prove: there are infinitely many prime numbers. Candidate shuffles in his chair, has no idea really. Professor tries to help: let's recall the definition of prime numbers. Let's talk about some examples. Etc etc. After 15 excruciating minutes, candidate summarizes progress thus: Professor, I now understand that all odd numbers are prime. But I still don't see why are there infinitely many...

Comment: That's an old joke.

Comment: I did say 1960s (-:

Answer (score 39):

Since the OP gave a physics example, here is another one, also at Princeton. Why are they always at Princeton? Student finishes his presentation on very mathematical aspects of string theory. An experimentalist on the committee asks him what he knows about the Higgs boson. He hems and haws and finally says "well, it was discovered a few years ago at Fermilab", Experimentalist: "Can you tell me the mass?" Student: "I think around 40 GeV."

This was more than 20 years ago and actually happened. I was there. The student passed, but the next year all Ph.D students working on string theory were required to take a course on the phenomenology of particle physics.

Comment: +1 for being there! On a related note I had a physics honours thesis defense panel which consisted _mainly_ of experimentalists (optics, atmospheric physics etc) and my thesis was on a mathematical aspect of string theory.

Comment: I was at another final oral where an experimentalist brought a thin box filled with small rods, a partition that looked like
/ \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \
dividing it into two sides but with gaps big enough for the rods to pass through, and a plexiglass top so you could see what was going on. Initially the rods were equally distributed, but after vigorous and random shaking by the student they all ended up on one side. The experimentalist then asked "Why doesn't this system violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics?" Those guys are tricky!

Comment: Jeff -- that's interesting. So why doesn't it?

Comment: I'm having trouble TeXing a more accurate drawing of the partition.
To get a more accurate picture type "backslash underscore slash space"
and repeat. This gives a partition which is not invariant under reflection, unlike my crude drawing above. It is now clearer why the rods can move more easily in one direction than the other, but of course this doesn't remove the conflict with the 2nd law. Continued in next comment.

Comment: After some discussion amongst the committee members it was finally decided that this must be a boundary effect and that in the infinite volume thermodynamic limit one would find equal numbers of rods on both sides but with some inhomogeneity near the boundary. I haven't been able to find a detailed analysis of this system so I don't know if this is in fact the correct answer.

Comment: Jeff: is this the same thing described in Matt Hastings' account? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends/53257#53257

Comment: It certainly seems to be, but I think he was at Princeton after it happened so he must have heard about it second hand. I hope he or someone else can give me a convincing explanation of what is actually going on. I'm really curious now after not thinking about it for 20 years.

Comment: More details below under Matt Hastings answer.

Comment: Was it maybe gravity or some assymetry of the boundary or the case that always pulled the rods to one side?


Answer (score 37):

Somebody posted the following:

> I have heard (from two sources) that at the University of Chicago a senior faculty member was temporarily banned from teaching undergraduate courses. The reason is that during a first semester undergraduate linear algebra course he did everything over the Quaternions.
>
> This one isn't so much academically scary, but my advisor told me that it was always interesting riding to conferences with the above professor because he would refuse to defrost the windshield so that he could draw diagrams on it and do math while he was driving.

Now I have never taught linear algebra at Chicago, since as somebody else pointed out we have no
undergraduate linear algebra courses, but in the 1960's and 1970's I did in fact drive to and from
seminars and conferences at Northwestern seminars without defrosting the windshield in order to have
a convenient blackboard.  I recall that it worked very well.

Peter May

Comment: I've heard the non-defrosting story told about R H Bing, who did this during heavy snow while driving people to Chicago.

Comment: Ooooh. Given the pretty drawings i've seen accompanying some of Bing's writing, it  is probably a pity no one saved at least some of those windshields in a freezer! Welcome to MO, by the way, Prof. May :)


Comment: Sounds silly—why quaternions? You can work using arbitrary skew fields.

Answer (score 36):

Not a horror story. On the much nicer end of the spectrum, there is a well-known urban legend about a student unwittingly solving an open problem, thinking it was homework. Though details of the tale may vary, there is at least one instance where the urban legend is true, [George Dantzig](http://www.snopes.com/college/homework/unsolvable.asp) in 1939. The funniest part of the story is when Don Knuth apparently came to learn of this story through a sermon by an Indiana pastor!

Comment: In the Hebrew University, it is told about Avinoam Mann.

Comment: At Princeton, it is told about (who else) Jack Milnor. The result is the "Fary-Milnor" theorem, on the total curvature of a knotted curve (there is an Annals paper to back up the story...)

Comment: The version I heard was that Milnor was late to class, and copied down several (open) problems written on the board that he thought were homework.  At a later class he says, "That homework was hard!  I only got 2 of them."

Comment: Paul Cohen used to claim that the Bergman kernel was discovered this way (by Bergman).

Comment: I heard it in reference to the discovery of Huffman codes.

Comment: The Huffman code story I heard is that in an information theory class, Huffman had a choice of writing a term paper or taking a final. His term paper was the discovery of an algorithm for finding optimal binary codes (i.e., Huffman codes).

Answer (score 33):

Once during a mathematical conversation with a student, [Alexander Grothendieck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck) was asked to consider an example of a prime number.

"You mean an actual prime number?"
The student replied, "Yes, an actual prime."

Grothendieck then said, "Alright then, take $57$".

-Taken from the Comme Appelé du Neant article in the Notices of the AMS

Comment: why, 57 is prime, up to multiplicative constants 

Answer (score 32):

As an undergraduate at Yale in the '70s I heard a variation on the basic legend, which I'll spell out a little since it has a slightly different moral from any others above.

Student goes to advisor saying I'd like to do a thesis generalizing the results in article X.
Advisor (and I think I heard it with Milnor as the advisor) says, "I don't recommend that because I don't think that's a very good article."  Student persists, writes thesis, states theorem at the defense and at that point the advisor rises to say "consider the following counterexample..."

---

I also heard a variation on "functions which turn out to be constant" legend.  But the version I heard has the thesis getting *accepted*, the vacuity of it contents going unnoticed for several years until an undergraduate supplies a one-line proof.

---

John Myhill told me about junior faculty at the University of Chicago about to grade qualifying exams in their legendarily ruthless way.  André Weil pops his head in the door
and says "Pass them all, they're no worse than you are."

Comment: That Weil anecdote is new to me, and highly amusing (not to mention salutary)

Comment: @Yemon  Graduate student that I was, the Myhill's story painted Weil for me as a hero.  Myhill, a very seasoned faculty member by then thought Weil came off as a monster.  A question of perspective I suppose.  Myhill did say that that year all the students passed. 

Comment: "Experience confirms that severity towards others and self-indulgence are one and the same vice" - La Bruyere (trans. Choi, probably badly)

Comment: And yes, as junior faculty myself, I'm not saying I would have welcomed such disdain from a doyen. But I still think it's a good cautionary tale, especially as I'll have qualifiers to mark later this year...

Comment: Usually, "be more lenient" is always advice that goes in the right direction for new (math) faculty.

Comment: @Yemon Choi : translation is ok : for completeness the original is :   
"L'expérience confirme que la mollesse ou l'indulgence pour soi,
Et la dureté pour les autres n'est qu'un seul et même vice."
Citation de Jean de La Bruyère ; Les Caractères, Du cœur - 1688.

Comment: @Feldman: The story would certainly paint Weil for me as a hero if he had said, "Pass them all, they're no worse than I am."

Answer (score 32):

As A.N.Whitehead, of PM fame, was still lecturing on mathematics at Cambrdge, he later became a philosopher in America, he arrived somewhat early in the lecture room one day. To fill in the time he started working on a problem from his research on the blackboard. As the students arrived he was still absorbed in his work so they sat down and waited for him to start the lecture. At the end of the allotted  time he was still working on his problem and so the students got up and left. Somewhat later he finished his work, packed up his things and went home. Arriving home he said to his wife, "You know a rather strange thing happened at the university today, nobody came to my lecture."

Answer (score 30):

I have no details to provide, but it is said that Ofer Gabber has derailed more than one talk at IHES after the speaker presents a definition by asking, "But what about the empty set?"

Comment: He has actually derailed many Sem. Bourbaki by asking a stream of questions in English (the official language was, and presumably still is, French), until the speaker would start speaking in English.

Comment: I don't think the Séminaire Bourbaki has an *official* language. Like any lecture in France (or, I guess, in a French-speaking country), it's just convenient to do it in French unless the speaker isn't francophone.

Comment: I recall a seminaire bourbaki in which Gabber persistently questioned Deligne in English, who answered just as persistently in French.

Answer (score 30):

One time Henri Berestycki was riding the Paris subway on the way to work and doing some calculations. All of a sudden, an elderly lady sitting across from him said: "Why don't you multiply by alpha and integrate by parts?" This did not solve his problem, but it was a reasonable thing to do.

It turned out the old lady had once worked with Lebesgue. She remembered J.L. Lions as a "clever lad."

I heard this story from my advisor Klaus Kirchgaessner who had heard it from Berestycki himself.

Comment: In the same spirit, I was sitting in a train, doing some mathematics. The person in front of me interupted me: *your formula for the derivative of a product is false*. Of course, he couldn't know that such a strange animal as a convolution product existed... 

Answer (score 28):

I've heard the following story (I don't know if it is true). A math professor gave his PhD student this journal paper, and asked him what consequences he could derive from it. The student started proving more and more interesting results based on this paper, until finally he proved a result that the professor knew was false. This led them to look more closely at the original journal paper, and upon close inspection, they discovered that it was wrong, rendering all the research the student had done so far worthless.

Comment: What is the worst known example of such a chain? Such as a 10 year old theory which based on completely false research?

Comment: I've actually seen something like this happen. 

Comment: That is a decisive argument for the motto "Give examples!". Examples are mental crutches, guides and railings too (as in this case) . - 

Answer (score 28):

I have heard (from two sources) that at the University of Chicago a senior faculty member was temporarily banned from teaching undergraduate courses. The reason is that during a first semester undergraduate linear algebra course he did everything over the Quaternions.

This one isn't so much academically scary, but my advisor told me that it was always interesting riding to conferences with the above professor because he would refuse to defrost the windshield so that he could draw diagrams on it and do math while he was driving.

Comment: Actually, that is not that bad of an idea! I *have* seen the face of my students when I tell them «you should go through your linear algebra notes to see how much of it carries over to the case of skew-fields» right before proceeding to pick a basis for an $\mathbb H$-module, say...

Comment: As an undergraduate I heard a secondhand story about a knot theorist teaching an introductory calculus class. The first question on the final was basic calculus; the rest involved knot theory.

Comment: In Germany many professors would be happy to get banned from teaching undergraduate courses (and behave accordingly). There used to be payment by number of students some years ago, but now it has been levelled, and teaching undergraduate courses has become nothing more than a chore people want to get rid of.

Comment: This story sounds strange to me because (at least the past few years, when I was there) the University of Chicago, SFAIK, doesn't *have* a straight-up linear algebra class for math majors.  The easier stuff you're basically expected to just up, the harder stuff gets stuffed into the general "algebra" sequence.

Comment: The story above takes place in the 1970's or earlier.

Comment: The second story is told, by Bus Jaco, about Bing.

Comment: Well, then it is true of at least two mathematicians and told by as many.

Comment: Concerning quaternions, there is also a story, which has happend in Cambridge as my brother told me: A professor asks in a lecture: "Is here somebody who does not know everything about quaternions?" A single student raises slowly her hand. "What?? Then learn it until tomorrow!" - it goes without saying that there were students in the class who did not raise their hand and did not even know what quaternions are...

Answer (score 28):

This story, according to the person I heard it from, happened some time in the 80s. It was about 10 years after Deligne's Hodge theory came out, but before Saito. It was not very clear how to define the mixed Hodge structure in non-constant cohomology. However, many people were convinced that such a thing existed (as turned out to be the case) and a number of competing proposals circulated. One such proposal was presented in a seminar talk where it was claimed that something was the "right Hodge filtration". At this moment Ofer Gabber (someone known, among other things, for giving hard time to speakers) intervened saying "What do you mean, the right Hodge filtration? What's the left Hodge filtration?"

Comment: Of course, if the talk were given in French, such a problem wouldn't have happened. (See Igor Rivin's comment below: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends/53176#53176 )

Comment: Sometimes the confusion has more tragic consequences: http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world-leftright-confusion-led-to-smog-air-crash-1242039.html

Comment: Ofer is a living legend, and stories about him as a graduate student at Harvard and permanent member of IHES abound. He is brilliant but demands a level of logical rigor and precision that even other mathematicians have difficulty providing. My understanding is that his name should be on many important papers, but he demanded that his name be removed because he was not comfortable with every detail stated in each paper.

Comment: I'd love to hear more of his stories!

Comment: My undergraduate career overlapped with Gabber's graduate student career. (He was a few years younger.) Once I had the satisfaction of offering a neat proof of some statement that came up in a differential geometry course we were both attending. My pleasure was not really dimmed by Ofer's comment that my proof did not work in characteristic $p$. 

Comment: @martin-brandenburg : Do you mean some more or much more?

Comment: @Jean-Charles: much more.

Answer (score 28):

When Peter Lax went to receive the national medal of science, he was asked by the other recipients about his merits. His answer was (apocryph) *I integrated by parts*.

Answer (score 24):

I heard the following story told about  [R. L. Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Lee_Moore).

It seems he was teaching a class in which several of the students were obnoxious and unruly.  So one day he walked into the lecture hall, opened his briefcase, took out a pistol, set it on the table in front of him, and then began to lecture as usual.  He had no further trouble with the rowdy students.

I have no particular reason to believe this is true, but it makes a good story.  I think I have seen other references to firearms in the math department at the University of Texas, though.

Comment: But I thought Moore didn't lecture!

Comment: I've heard this story too.

Comment: As in all the best urban legends, it does not really matter if it's true or not: it does sound like something Moore would do.

Comment: I think Moore gave lectures in some of his classes at some points of his career.  

Comment: A friend of the family claims that in first grade, his teacher had a glass eye. The students didn't know until he had to leave the room to go to the bathroom.  As he got up to go, he took out his eye and placed it on the table saying "Be good while I am gone - I'm watching you".  These are 6 year olds...

Comment: What Pete said is correct. Mary Ellen Rudin recounts in her interview for More Mathematical People that Moore gave lectures for calculus classes, and Halmos in his automathography recalls being permitted to sit in on one of Moore's calculus lectures. I think nevertheless that he would send students to the board in such classes. 

Answer (score 21):

I heard this story a couple of years back (not sure though if it is true): 
A young Japanese mathematician was giving a talk based on his results at Courant Institute. His work was built on the work of S.R.S Varadhan. But apparently during the talk Varadhan had his eyes closed and the speaker mistook it for him sleeping. He made a joke by saying somthing like "hopefully not everybody is sleeping". A few minutes later Varadhan open his eyes and said "consider this counterexample". 
But Varadhan liked the speaker's idea and invited him to spent some time at Courant institute. The correct result is now known as 'Speaker'-Varadhan theorem.

Comment: I suppose you mean S.R.S.Varadhan?

Comment: Haha. Last August at the ICM, when he was chairing a session, even I thought he was sleeping. :)

Answer (score 21):

From the article "A credo of sorts" by Vaughan Jones, in the book "Truth in Mathematics":

> Once, at a seminar, one of the world's best low-dimensional topologists was presenting a major result.  At a certain point another distinguished topologist in the audience intervened to say he did not understand how the speaker did a certain thing.  The speaker gave an anguished look and gazed at the ceiling for at least a minute.  The member of the audience then affirmed "Oh yes, I hadn't thought of that!"  Visibly relieved, the speaker went on with his talk, glad to have communicated this point to the audience.

Comment: We had a lecturer in Bielefeld whose proofs were sometimes a bit terse. From time to time he had spend a minute or a few after writing down the proof at the blackboard before he remembered (silently) the point and drew the square. 

Answer (score 21):

There is this story set at Harvard.  During the Vietnam War there was a student strike.  One math professor goes to his graduate course and finds the room empty.  But he delivers his lecture anyway as usual.  When he gets back to his office and tells someone about it, they ask him why he did that.  He replies, "So I'll know where to start next time."

Comment: Isn't this one already in the list?

Comment: an unfortunate feature of "big list" questions that revive after many months

Answer (score 20):

A Japanese professor writes a letter to his American colleague, asking to send a preprint.
The letter (very long and polite) is finished with the sentence:

**"Please forgive me my shameless desire."**

Answer (score 19):

Here is a story I heard when I was student.

Professor S.'s student had finished his dissertation to everybody's satisfaction. All that was pending was his advisor's signature. S. agreed to sign on one (half joking?) condition: The student had to defeat S. in a *jalapeño-eating* contest.

For some reason the student agreed. (Hopefully this is not just a plot device. If the story is true, I would like one day to ask the student what he was thinking.)

They went to S.'s favorite Thai restaurant. He explained to the staff the contest. They set up a table for them, and brought them jalapeños, they would eat them, new (hotter) ones would be brought, etc. The whole staff was watching and having a great time.

The poor student, of course, was suffering, really worried that perhaps S. was serious, and he would never get his degree, since it soon became clear S. was going to defeat the student without difficulties. S. would grab the jalapeños and eat them while explaining where they were from and what the ideal way to prepare them was.

At some point, a drop of sweat from S.'s brow was threatening to fall into his eye, and without realizing what he was doing, S. passed his finger through his eye to remove the sweat.

Apparently the pain was agonizing, and the student got his dissertation signed.

Comment: @Andres: I like this as a story, but not as an answer to this question.  Most of these stories are interesting because they tell us something that we recognize (or enunciate things we fear) about the math profession.  But where's the math in your story?  Are mathematicians notorious jalapeno poppers?  [Sorry to be a stick in the mud.]

Comment: The fear isn't mathematical but academic: to get one's thesis approved there are dozens of (to us inconsequential) hurdles, including margins, fonts, citation styles, microfiche fees and, for one unlucky acolyte, jalapenos.

Comment: @Kevin: I have my neuroses (and so do they!), but I confess that fear of jalapenos does not hit very close to home.

Answer (score 19):

There's a bar in Bonn, which has the name 'Blow up' and closes only very late at night. At some occasion, an algebraic geometer A was in this bar well beyond midnight and was getting quite drunk. After some time, he decided it would be a very good idea to explain to some person B in the bar he only met this night what a blow up is in mathematics. And so he starts to explain until B interrupts him: "Hey, I know all this stuff. I've done my diploma thesis in Estonia in complex geometry."

Since I know A (although I heard the story fromy someone else), I suppose this has happened essentially this way.

Answer (score 18):

In the early eighties, fleeing from Romania, C. Foias got a professorship position in Orsay. He gave a graduate course on 'Contractions et dilatations' (*Contractions and dilations*). Someone handwrote on the annoucement 'Is this a course on Obstetrics ?'.

Answer (score 18):

The wikipedia entry for [Borel summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation) narrates the following recollection by Mark Kac, about an encounter between Emile Borel and Mittag-Leffler. This is one of my favourites.

"Borel, then an unknown young man, discovered that his summation method gave the 'right' answer for many classical divergent series. He decided to make a pilgrimage to Stockholm to see Mittag-Leffler, who was the recognized lord of complex analysis. Mittag-Leffler listened politely to what Borel had to say and then, placing his hand upon the complete works by Weierstrass, his teacher, he said in Latin, 'The Master forbids it'."

Answer (score 18):

Heard from Carsten Thomassen:

He was giving a lecture on matchings in graph theory, and presented a game where two players would alternately pick some edge in a graph, and at the end one person would win (i do not remember the exact rules of the game). Then Carsten asked the students, which player would win this game. A student raised his hand and replied "You will".

Answer (score 16):

I've heard the following story (don't know if it was true, or who was supposedly involved):

As is well-known, at a certain big-name university the advisor defends the student's thesis. A student worked with a certain big-shot for five years and produced what many looked at as a fine dissertation. The day of the defence came. The advisor got up to the board, gave a quick introduction, and embarked on stating the main theorem in the dissertation. Half way through writing it, he put down the chalk, and paced around a bit. He then turned, apologized, and said, "I'm sorry, but I think I've found a counterexample."

Comment: If we're thinking of the same big-name university, then I heard that the impetus for the whole "advisor defends the student's thesis" system arose from an advisor making a quip along the lines of "this is the best thesis I ever wrote" in a defense prior to this system.  It's not clear why this would have been an effective solution to this sort of problem, so this is probably pure apocrypha.  Amusing nonetheless!

Comment: I have heard the same story as Ramsey, about the same university -- but the quip is supposed to be "OK, so it's not the best thesis I ever wrote!"

Comment: @JSE: Actually, that sounds right, and makes a lot more sense...

Comment: When I was in grad school, a senior mathematician told me: "I never minded writing a student's dissertation, but I draw the line at having to explain it to him or her".

Comment: There's an old joke-definition of a dissertation, something like, "a research paper written by a senior academic under the most trying circumstances." 

Comment: Yep, JSE has the wording right in that story.

Comment: This all somehow reminds me of a quote (supposedly from Haydn) "Don't make a sour face when listening to opening notes of a sonata written by some grand duke: you never know who actually composed it".

Comment: @JSE, KConrad: I tell that story often (and in exactly the same way as JSE did).  Of course, I use the advisor's actual name [I don't know the name of the student, and it would probably be too cruel to include it if I did].  

Comment: I never heard a version of this story with names!

Comment: @JSE: Well, I guess we will have something to talk about the next time we meet.  (BTW, I just finished rereading your book.  You'll be happy to know that I bought a copy this time.)

Comment: Dear JSE, I though we heard it at the same time, in a sit-down conversation between Joe Harris and the grad students, and he named the advisor.  (At least, I have in mind that I know who the advisor was, and Joe definitely told us a version of the story, so I've always presumed that he told us the advisor's name.)  (Like Pete, I tell this story quite a bit, with the advisor's name included.)

Comment: I also tell the story with the advisor's name included, as well as the other senior faculty member who provoked him.  I think I heard the story around the time I graduated, I believe from the thesis advisor of four contributors to this thread.

Answer (score 14):

Apparently a postdoc at IHES cornered Dennis Sullivan back in the eighties, and asked him a long and involved question concerning the stuff the postdoc was studying. Dennis' response was:

That's a good question! I think you should work on it!

Comment: I'm surprised there aren't more Dennis Sullivan stories here. He's definitely one of the more colorful mathematicians of our time.

Answer (score 14):

When I took analysis from Paul Sally, he claimed that a student once asked him in class, "Professor Sally, why is it called the p-adic *norm*?  If it's a norm, what does it measure?"  Without thinking, Paul loudly replied, "Well, it measures the p-ness of a number."

I suspect that he just substituted himself into an existing urban legend, yet I would not be surprised if it were true.

Comment: The related story that I've heard (from people who were there, I believe) is that in the early 1970s in the Ohio State summer math program for high school kids an elderly female European giving a lecture about finite groups once innocently said, in coming to a key step in a proof: "But we still haven't used the $p$-ness of the group."

Answer (score 12):

I have a story of this kind. My thesis advisor J.-M. Souriau used to talk this story about one of his close friend (I'll keep quiet the name) : "Avant de devenir directeur de l'école normale supérieure (Ulm) il a passé la moitié de sa vie mathématique à définir le nombre de [[put his name here]] et l'autre moité à démontrer qu'il était égal à 1." I don't know if it is true, I doubt but not that much :-)

Comment: Is this poor soul's number a candidate for http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32967/have-any-long-suspected-irrational-numbers-turned-out-to-be-rational ?

Comment: OK... So how many mathematicians have been directors of "L'Ecole" recently?... The identity of the poor soul should be easy t work out.

Comment: Well, I guess there are two candidates, actually. One more than I expected...

Answer (score 12):

Here's another story not particularly relevant to the original question: When I was a graduate student at Harvard, there was a much older Greek graduate student (whose name I forget) who was viewed by at least some of my classmates as being one of if not the smartest graduate students there. I was told that he was responsible for providing the critical ideas for least two classmates' Ph.D. theses. But he never completed a thesis himself and, as I recall, found a good career working for the European Community in Brussels.

Answer (score 12):

Ed Dean linked to this story in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends/53184#53184), but I think it is too nice to stay hidden there:

On December 5, 1947, Einstein and Morgenstern accompanied Gödel to his U.S. citizenship exam, where they acted as witnesses. Gödel had confided in them that he had discovered an inconsistency in the U.S. Constitution, one that would allow the U.S. to become a dictatorship. Einstein and Morgenstern were concerned that their friend's unpredictable behavior might jeopardize his chances. Fortunately, the judge turned out to be Phillip Forman. Forman knew Einstein and had administered the oath at Einstein's own citizenship hearing. Everything went smoothly until Forman happened to ask Gödel if he thought a dictatorship like the Nazi regime could happen in the U.S. Gödel then started to explain his discovery to Forman. Forman understood what was going on, cut Gödel off, and moved the hearing on to other questions and a routine conclusion.

(cited from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_G%C3%B6del#Relocation_to_Princeton.2C_Einstein_and_US_citizenship))

EDIT: Thanks to Gerald Edgar (and Google) you can find the answer to what the loophole in the US Constitution is [here](http://blog.plover.com/law/Godel-dictatorship-2.html).

Comment: I am extremely curious as to what this inconsistency is.

Comment: I am as well.                          .

Comment: Perhaps these guys are unable to use Google for some reason...
http://blog.plover.com/law/Godel-dictatorship-2.html  


Answer (score 12):

This may be an urban legend, but it's true as far as I know.

During R. L. Moore's reign at University of Texas, sometimes a grad student would be awarded a PhD for work that was original *for the student* even if it had been done before.

Moore insisted that students reproduce everything from scratch (though guided with Socratic questions). This produced outstanding students, at first. But it got to be a tragedy by the time Moore was put out to pasture. The gap between what students graduated knowing and the vanguard of research became insurmountable.

This was before my time, but I did speak to someone who said that he recused himself from a PhD committee shortly after coming to UT because he could not sign off on a dissertation whose results he knew were not original.

Answer (score 11):

One urban legend I remember was of a student who just wanted to schedule a language exam, but the professor opened a text to the introduction and asked him to translate it. The student asked to switch to the mathematics, saying, "I don't know any verbs!"

Comment: That is not an urban legend, well, at least not the first half. My (French) language examiner at Princeton was disappointed that I brought a mathematics textbook (in French) for the exam. After looking around and couldn't find a French-language *roman* handy in his office, he begrudgingly passed me after I translated the Preface and Acknowledgements (in addition to several mathematics-laden passages from the middle of the book).

Comment: I once took a math course for which the textbook was in French although the course was otherwise taught in English.  You don't need to know much French to understand that sort of thing.

Comment: I heard from an older student in college that Nick Katz taught a course on local class field theory using Serre's Corps Locaux and  that student didn't realize the book had been translated into English until after the course was over. 

Comment: @Michael: Some fellow student of mine went to a course (in the US) where all literature was Chinese, and the lecturer being surprised about him showing up had a hard time giving the lecture in English. My friend didn't stay long in that course...

Comment: @Someone: I actually dragged a Serbian friend of mine to seminar just for that. Otherwise they'd look at me and give the discussion in Chinese, and while it is my native language, it is by far *not* my native *mathematical* language. 

Comment: @Willie: I'm happy *not* to be a friend of yours ;-).

Comment: Have you ever tried reading a mathematics textbook in Greek? It's surprisingly easy.

Answer (score 11):

Bob Stong told me that a Ph.D. candidate once presented his thesis in topology without any examples.  One of the committee asked for any space for which the work was true.  The student said that he had yet to think of one.  He was failed in short order.  I seem to remember that the story was from University of Chicago, but I could be wrong.  Whether Professor Stong was pulling my leg or not is not known.

Comment: I was actually present for something like this.  This was in Oregon, maybe 15 years ago.  The speaker lectured for 75 minutes on the cohomoolyg of a certain class of spaces.  I was a beginning graduate student at the time, so I didn't really understand the talk, but, apparently, the class of spaces had very unusual properties.  Someone asked - as in your story - at the end of the talk if the speaker could give an accessible example of this class.  The speaker said, unabashed, that he couldn't.  In fact, he strongly suspected that there were \textit{no} examples at all!

Comment: I don't think this is so unreasonable. I am sure many people try to characterize, eg, $\{x | \zeta(x)=0, \Re(x) \neq \frac12\}.$

Comment: I heard once that Cauchy wrote a paper about "Bounded Entire Functions". 

From what I know, he later proved the Liouville Theorem.

Comment: The paper at http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2010/171-1/p10
which is based on a PhD thesis, makes Igor's point even better than his example does.

Comment: I agree with Igor; people talk about the properties of odd perfect numbers all the time. 

Comment: [Igor probably meant to include a hypothesis such as $x \notin \bf Z$ :-)]

Comment: Long ago I attended a colloquium at Harvard at which a famous mathematician presented a talk on "Banach categories" intended to generalize work of Bott.  At the end, Bott asked whether there were any examples other than the traditional ones, (perhaps sections of vector bundles on certain manifolds).  The answer: "No, I don't know of any."

Answer (score 10):

I heard this in Oxford in 1970.  I can't believe it:

A PhD student decides to see what happens if he assumes the inverse of the triangle inequality. He finds he can prove that there are various interesting consequences - for instance, certain sets of points must be collinear.  He eventually writes it all up as his thesis.  His examiner starts with the question, "are you aware that such a space can only contain one point?"

Comment: Perhaps this is another variant of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends/53127#53127 ?

Comment: This was a question on one of our Analysis II problem sheets at Cambridge.

Comment: I wondered about that some time ago, too, but was relieved of the tension here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23113/is-there-any-geometry-where-the-triangle-inquality-fails

Answer (score 7):

Lacking sufficient reputation on this site to comment on posts, I'm going to make this an answer, and you know it's a true urban legend if you read the posts above.  Once, at a Princeton physics exam, a group of the senior Princeton physics faculty were trying to figure out why, when you shake a bunch of rods in a container with certain asymmetries in  the geometry of the container, the rods assume a "more ordered" state (they tended to concentrate on one side), and they couldn't figure out why this did not contradict the second law of thermodynamics!  In an amazing twist, they speculated that the result had to do with finite size effects.....

(for those who aren't in on why this is just too crazy to believe: the shaken container is not a closed system, so the second law doesn't apply.  Further, the forces on the rods, a combination of shaking and frictional forces, do not correspond to thermal noise and dissipation, so there is no reason for the system to go to thermal equilibrium.  It's like asking why, when there is a baited mousetrap and a live mouse in the room at time t=0, is it the case that after a certain amount of time the entropy decreases in that the mouse is more likely to be in the mousetrap than not.  I think the most clever answer for the student is: "I notice that this exam has gone on for 30 minutes already and you are still walking and talking.  Why are you not relaxing to thermal equilibrium?  Perhaps the food you ate this morning is helping keep you out of equilibrium?")

:-)

Comment: I was one of those confused professors (although not senior) and you may well be right that finite size effects have nothing to do with it, but I don't find your analogy terribly convincing either. Do you think the behavior would not have been observed if the system was just coupled to a heat bath rather than shaken? I'd really enjoy hearing a more detailed analysis of what is going on.

Comment: If the system was in thermal equilibrium with a heat bath, then indeed this behavior would not happen.  Two caveats: first (a technical point): of course, in true thermal equilibrium the rods would combust with the oxygen in the air, etc... but at intermediate time scales we can ignore that and consider an ensemble of rods being equally likely to be distributed anywhere.  Second, even in thermal equilibrium there can be some interesting entropic effects near a boundary; basically, yes, there can be some finite size effects due to, say, more available orientations near one side of the boundary.

Comment: (continuing the previous comment).  However, those finite size effects are going to be much weaker than the observed effect (_all_ rods on one side) and will lead to only a slight bias.  For a detailed analysis, one can consider Feynman's ratchet-and-pawl calculation (the same calculation appears in a lot of places).  If you take the ratchet-and-pawl calculation and make even some slight change in the dynamics driving the system (for example, change the noise applied to the system to have a non-thermal spectrum) then generically this does lead to a net "current".

Comment: it is a condensed matter analogue of the "anything not forbidden is compulsory" in particle physics.  Consider a particle at point x in a potential U(x) with some non-thermal noise and a damping (so force=U'-eta v+noise, where eta is friction and noise has non-thermal spectrum).  Suppose the potential has a sawtooth shape.  This shape destroys reflection symmetry.  The non-thermal noise then means detailed balance is broken, and so nothing forbids a current.  If you pick a generic potential and non-thermal noise an dissipation and run it on a computer, odds are you will see the current.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I talked to my local condensed matter guru and he also emphasized the role of dissipation, although in this system it is not clear without more analysis whether dissipation in collisions between the rods or in the rod-boundary collisions is more important in driving the system. Amusingly you can replace the rods by spheres and make the barrier symmetric and you will still get an accumulation on one side, but which side it is will be random. Dissipation from collisions increases at higher density and cool the system, so a fluctuation towards higher density grows.

Comment: Yes, Chicago has some real experts on this kind of thing!  My favorite absolutely bizarre thing I learned about in Chicago has to do with the "brazil nut" effect, that if you shake a jar of mixed nuts, the brazil nuts (the bigger ones) tend to wind up on top.  Well, I'd heard about that effect before visiting Chicago, and you can try to puzzle out what happens, why exactly the Brazil nuts wind up on top.  So, the crazy thing I learned is that if you repeat the experiment in a vacuum (or maybe it was just in a different liquid, I forget the exact details), the effect is reversed!

Comment: @matt-hastings: I think you would need a dense liquid in which the nuts want to float, based on the explanations I've heard of the phenomenon. On the other hand, you also do not want a fluid that increases drag, which will enhance the effect. Lastly: granular flow may be a matter of life-and-death! Imagine an avalanche...

Answer (score 6):

Professor A at Harvard told the following story, supposedly a first hand account of his student days at Chicago, though it never struck me as remotely plausible.  (I think he just told it so that he would seem like a teddy bear in comparison.)  But I wonder if anyone else has heard variants of this.

At the beginning of a course, Professor X would start asking some reasonable questions, the answers to which students taking the course could be expected to already know.  Finally, he would ask one unfortunate student a question which no one taking the course would be able to answer.  Upon the student's failure to answer correctly, Professor X wouldn't explain that the student's ignorance was justified, instead letting this event undermine the student's confidence about taking the course.  Professor X would continue to single out this poor target for humiliation until he or she finally dropped the course.  Professor A claimed to believe that Professor X's motivation was to have lit a fire under the remaining students and make them band together.

Again, it's a rather unlikely tale of abuse.  Though perhaps with a plant "student" playing along as the victim it could be an effective ploy ...

Comment: A version of this happened at my undergraduate institution, but with a plant student. At the very first lecture, the professor sent the plant student to the blackboard and assigned a difficult exercise. The plant student does a nice job (one much better than any other students could do presumably), but the professor gives him a really hard time, harping on any flaw and concluding that this was "barely the level required to survive this lecture". The next day, six students had given up the course, so that the professor had to make sure words reached them that it was all a joke.

Comment: Example of a plant student: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hut3VRL5XRE

Answer (score 4):

Prof. M eventually says to his student: "There's nothing more I can teach you on this subject, I'll have to send you to Prof. B". So the student goes to study with Prof. B. A few months later he returns to Prof. M, a whimpering wreck. Prof. M calls up Prof. B. "What did you do to my student?" "You told me to stretch him." "Yes, but not on the rack.".

OTOH Another Prof. B told me that this was exactly the kind of story that the original Prof. B used to calculatedly spread about himself to give himself a certain reputation.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard stories about von Neumann chatting up recent Ph.D.'s and solving their thesis problems in his head.  An incident along those lines is recounted in Sylvia Nasar's biography of John Nash.  Perhaps someone here can shed some light on which von Neumann stories are purely mythological?

Answer (score 4):

This actually happened in one of the initial lectures in an introductory course in linear algebra. This was an altogether new experience for us to get acquainted with abstract way of thinking. So the teacher said -"Let a, b and c be three linearly independent vectors in the vector space R^n." A guy interjected -" Sir, can you be more concrete?" "Ok"-said the professor and continued - ""Let alpha, beta and gamma be three linearly independent vectors in R^n".

Comment: I don't really get it...The joke is that some professor thinks that "$\alpha$" is more concrete than "a"?  To me that's just weird.

Comment: I once asked a professor a question of the form, "So method *A* can be used to work with the object and we have that it is equivalent to method *B*" and got "You can ride the bus to school if you can ride the bus to school" in response.  That was his way of answering, Yes, and showing that at some level, mentally results become indistinguishable and perhaps you can no longer explain it any simpler.  You've forgotten what it was like to not know!

Answer (score 4):

Allegedly, when Peter Lax was receiving his National Medal of Science, everyone had to describe their more notable accomplishments, and being somewhat cowed by the tales of curing cancer, turning water into wine, etc, etc, when the turn came to him, his description of his accomplishments was:

I integrated by parts...

Comment: Denis Serre has unfortunately already posted this... 

Comment: Not so unfortunate, but I should pay more attention:)

Answer (score 3):

(A rather sad story)

For obvious reasons, I won't give the place and/or names.

On a thesis defence (we have here a procedure very different from Europe or US; for instance, the committee is more or less fixed) one member of the committee rose and asked to vote against the thesis because of plagiarism: the thesis contained (almost *verbatim*!) definitions from a book X.

Comment: I don't understand, were the definitions supposed to be part of the original work of the author?

Comment: @Sean I had understood that as being the point of the story.

Comment: It's possible for a definition to be creative or unique; in such case it should have been cited.

Answer (score 3):

When I was a grad student, I lived across the street from an electronics store. The owner of the store  had done some graduate work (in some sort of Engineering, I think). He ran a weekly ad in the local newspaper, and placed at the bottom of the ad a relatively hard math problem. And he gave anyone who could solve the problem the choice of a free radio or telephone (each of which would retail for less than ten dollars). After solving one of his problems, and speaking with him for a bit, I convinced him to place a problem from group theory (it was about equations over the group $Z_2$) in the next ad.

The next week the ad came out. My problem was there in print. My first publication. A few days later I went to talk to the owner of the store. He was furious. A whole bunch of people had come in with solutions and he gave away a lot of free radios and telephones.

The sad thing was that none of the solutions were correct.

EDIT- now for the mathematical urban legend...

A well-known topologist, let's call him X, told me that this had happened to him. He had been in a seminar for graduate students. The student speaker was proving one of X's theorems. X found this boring and fell asleep. And he started snoring.

They had to wake him up because no one could hear the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the story of the young mathematician which speaks in a conference, and at the end of his talk a (famous) mathematician provides a counterexample to his main theorem. This is just another variation to the story posted by WW.

I head this story from couple people (they claim they were there), but, if I recall right, I also read it in "The Puzzling adventures of Dr. Ecco".

Comment: I know one case when that actually happened only it was not a conference but a colloquium, it was a famous (OK, not a celebrity, but still...) mathematician who was giving the talk, and it was a young fellow who gave a counterexample. I'll not disclose the names but if you really want to dig for the details, search east of lake Erie... 

Comment: I've heard of that happen, and the speaker, after a moment of silence, admits, "yup, it's rubbish," and sits down in mid-talk. The person who found the counterexample, although a student then, is now a fairly well-known mathematician.

Comment: I witnessed something like that happening at a conference some 20 years ago. About 15 minutes into a talk a Fields medalist in the audience commented loudly (and laughing....!) that a "theorem" just written on the board couldn't possibly be true for this and that reason. The speaker blushed, stared silently at the board for a couple of minutes and then had to admit that he was wrong. We had a longer-than-usual coffee break.......

Comment: Concerning these stories I always ask myself: Does "wrong" mean that the theorem is absolutely wrong, or that we can repair it by, say, adding some assumptions or modifying the definitons?

Comment: @Andrea: I did not post this story because I only heard it second hand, but the way you describe the Field medalist (loud and laughing) makes me think it's the exact same incident that I heard about from somebody else who witnessed it. It sounded absolutely mortifying.

Comment: I witnessed an incident with perhaps a better moral.  Immediately after or maybe during a conference talk (some 35 years ago) by a young analyst, it was noticed that the main claim could not be right.  The speaker was dejected but one famous listener, possibly Joe Kohn, responded: "Look, even if that statement is wrong, you are proving Something, let's just see what it is."  I believe they shortly arrived at a correct version, and the young man was relieved, but the kind helpfulness and the positive attitude was the main lesson I took away.

Answer (score 0):

Was the Chicago professor M. H. Stone of Stone-Weierstrass fame?
Prof. Abhyankar has several times recollected his lectures at tata institute,
which he attended as an undergraduate student, starting with : let X be a Hilbert space, over reals or complex nos or quaternions.

Comment: I believe it is the same stone.

Answer (score -9):

In a fabulous French comedy [La moutarde me monte au nez](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071863/) Pierre Richard's character is a maths teacher at a local girls' college. One day he accidentally ends up in a mansion that belongs to an American movie star (Jane Birkin). Frighened of a potentially dangerous intruder, she sets her pet cheetah on him, and the academic promptly jumps on a huge chandelier.

To prove to her that he was indeed a maths lecturer, he had to answer a few questions. First - to expand $(ax+b)^2$ (which he did) and then - to integrate $\sin(ax+b)$ (again, success). All that - hanging from a chandelier, with a cheetah pacing below.

Only after that she allows him to climb down to the floor... and then they have a romantic dinner, needless to say.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an urban legend.