# Is the equivalence $\mathrm{CRing}^{\mathrm{op}}\simeq \mathrm{AffSch}$ related to the homotopy hypothesis?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

At the heart of algebraic geometry lies the op-equivalence between commutative rings and affine schemes, i.e.,
$$\mathrm{CRing}^{\mathrm{op}}\simeq \mathrm{Aff\,Sch}.$$

At the heart of homotopy theory lies the equivalence of $\infty$-groupoids and spaces, i.e.,
$$\infty\text{-}\mathrm{Gpd}\simeq \mathrm{Spc}.$$

On the lefthand sides are (different but related) algebraic structures and on the right hand side are (different but related kinds of) spaces.
Can something nontrivial (and cool) be said about the similarities here?

Comment: I think yes but only in a general, vague sense. Both are concerned with the bigger program of geometry/algebra duality in general, but I fail to see any deep connections...

Comment: The fact that the opposite category is involved in one but not the other seems problematic.

Comment: This reminds me of [an old joke](https://mathoverflow.net/a/53228/11640) about the Grothendieck–Riemann–Roch theorem...

Comment: groups and rings are related and so are affine schemes and spaces.